# Make the Google python client library for accessing Google cloud storage hit a stubbed API

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-cloud-storage

I am writing an application that uses Google's python client for GCS.

https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/reference/libraries#client-libraries-install-python

I've had no issues using this, until I needed to write my functional tests.

The way our organization tests integrations like this is to write a simple stub of the API endpoints I hit, and point the Google client library (in this case) to my stub, instead of needing to hit Google's live endpoints.

I'm using a service account for authentication and am able to point the client at my stub when fetching a token because it gets that value from the service account's json key that you get when you create the service account.

What I don't seem able to do is point the client library at my stubbed API instead of making calls directly to Google.

Some work arounds that I've though of, that I don't like are:
- Allow the tests to hit the live endpoints.
- Put in some configuration that toggles using the real Google client library, or a mocked version of the library. I'd rather mock the API versus having mock code deployed to production.

Any help with this is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I’ve made some research and it seems like there’s nothing supported specifically for Cloud Storage using python. I found this GitHub issue [entry](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-go/issues/592) with a related discussion, but for go.

I think you can open a [public issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187243&template=0) asking for this functionality. I’m afraid by now it’s easier to keep using your second workaround.